# Post a specific counter inside a while loop to another page

Tags: php, html

I have some table rows inside a while loop, the rows are all data from my database, each row has a submit button. I want to post specific data to another page, for example, if I press submit_3 then I want to post all data of row 3 to otherpage.php, but the way I tried it, it always uses the last row.

For example, I have 25 rows, then I submit button 3 and it will post all information from row 25.

```
print '<form method="POST" action="edit.php" name="action">';
//print '<input type="hidden" value="'.$imId.'" name="imId">';
print '<div class="tbl-content">';
print '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
print '<tbody>';

$querySelect = "select hersteller, name, kaufDatum, category, ablaufDatum, imID, details from inventoryManager ";
$querySelect .= $orderBy;

error_log( "SQL2:" . $querySelect . "<br>", 3, "C:/Control/log/debug/dp.html" );
$resultSelect = db_query( [ $querySelect ] );

while ( ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultSelect ) ) ) {
    $manufacturer   = $row[ hersteller ];
    $name           = $row[ name ];
    $buyDate        = $row[ kaufDatum ];
    $selectCategory = $row[ category ];
    $expireDate     = $row[ ablaufDatum ];
    $imId           = $row[ imID ];
    $details        = $row[ details ];

    print '<tr>';
    print "<td>$manufacturer</td>";
    print "<td>$name</td>";
    print "<td>$buyDate</td>";
    print "<td>$selectCategory</td>";
    print "<td>$expireDate</td>";
    //error_log("imIdCheck#1:".$imId."<br>",3,"C:/Control/log/debug/dp.html");
    print '<td><input type="submit" name="edit_' . $imId . '" value="Bearbeiten" class="button2 button3"></td>';
    print '</tr>';
}
print '</tbody>';
print '</table>';
print '</div>';
print '</form>';
```

On the other page, I select all data with the $imId, but every time I press a submit button even if its submit_1 I get the last possible step.
What do I have to include that it submits the data of the choosed row?

Edit: Some of the HTML-Code after implementing a suggestion to have a button:

```
<form method="POST" action="edit.php" name="action">
<div class="tbl-content">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>TestName</td>
      <td>2019-03-23</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-03-22</td>
      <input type="hidden" value="2" name="imId">
      <td>
         <button type="submit" name="id" value="2" class="button2 button3">Bearbeiten</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>TestHersteller</td>
      <td>TestName</td>
      <td>2019-03-31</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2019-03-31</td>
      <input type="hidden" value="3" name="imId">
      <td>
         <button type="submit" name="id" value="3" class="button2 button3">Bearbeiten</button>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191514/discussion-on-question-by-xxy-post-a-specific-counter-inside-a-while-loop-to-ano).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ONE form, then my suggestion of having the named submit button send the ID  will work if you remove the hidden field. Make sure you spell imID the way you read and write it in the php and a click on each button will send a the ID in the value of the clicked button to the server

```
<button type="submit" name="imID" value="'.$imId.'" class="button2 button3">Bearbeiten/button>
```

Like this:

```html
<form method="POST" action="edit.php" name="action">
  <div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>TestName</td>
          <td>2019-03-23</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>2019-03-22</td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" name="imID" value="2" class="button2 button3">Bearbeiten</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TestHersteller</td>
          <td>TestName</td>
          <td>2019-03-31</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>2019-03-31</td>
          <td>
            <button type="submit" name="imID" value="3" class="button2 button3">Bearbeiten</button>

            ....
```